# Error Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed laravel y sesion

Tags: laravel

estoy trabajando con un formulario de varios pasos, tengo en una vista un formulario que deben llenar con cierta información y un boton siguiente para pasara la otra vista con otro formulario, voy guardando en cada paso la información en una sesion correspondiente al paso (ejemplo paso1, paso 2) el problema es que uno de estos formularios tengo que subir archivos (fotos y pdf) y me esta arrojando el error:

**Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed**

Estuve leyendo y al parecer es porque en una sesion no se pueden almacenar archivos

En el controlador, la funcion del el paso del formulario de subida de archivos lo tengo asi:

```
public function paso2_validacion(Request $request){




    $rules = [
        'datos_conductor_nombre'  => 'required|max:40',
        'datos_conductor_rut'  => 'required|max:40',
        'datos_conductor_direccion'  => 'required|max:40',
        'datos_conductor_comuna'  => 'required|max:40',
        'datos_conductor_ciudad'  => 'required|max:40',
        'datos_conductor_region'  => 'required|max:40',
        'datos_conductor_email'  => 'required|max:30',
        'datos_conductor_telefono'  => 'required|max:11',
         'datos_conductor_carnet_delantero' =>'required',
   /*   'datos_conductor_carnet_trasero' =>'required',
       'datos_conductor_licencia_delantera' =>'required',
       'datos_conductor_licencia_trasera_1' =>'required' */
     ];

    $messages = [
        'datos_conductor_nombre.required' =>'Ingrese Nombre completo conductor',
        'datos_conductor_nombre.max' =>'Maximo 40 caracteres',
        'datos_conductor_rut.required' =>'Ingrese Nombre completo conductor',
        'datos_conductor_rut.max' =>'Maximo 40 caracteres',
        'datos_conductor_direccion.required' =>'Ingrese dirección conductor',
        'datos_conductor_direccion.max' =>'Maximo 40 caracteres',
        'datos_conductor_comuna.required' =>'Ingrese Comuna',
        'datos_conductor_comuna.max' =>'Maximo 40 caracteres',
        'datos_conductor_ciudad.required' =>'Ingrese Ciudad',
        'datos_conductor_ciudad.max' =>'Maximo 40 caracteres',
        'datos_conductor_region.required' =>'Ingrese Región',
        'datos_conductor_region.max' =>'Maximo 40 caracteres',
        'datos_conductor_email.required' =>'Ingrese Email conductor',
        'datos_conductor_email.max' =>'Maximo 30 caracteres',
        'datos_conductor_telefono.required' =>'Ingrese teléfono conductor',
        'datos_conductor_telefono.max' =>'Maximo 11 caracteres',
        'datos_conductor_carnet_delantero.required' =>'Debe cargar Documento Carnet Delantero',
    /*     'datos_conductor_carnet_trasero.required' =>'Debe cargar Documento Carnet Trasero',
        'datos_conductor_licencia_delantera.required' =>'Debe cargar Documento Licencia Delantero',
        'datos_conductor_licencia_trasera_1.required' =>'Debe cargar Documento Licencia trasero',  *///Debe cargar Documento Licencia trasero

    ];



    $data2 = $request->validate($rules, $messages);

    /* $uploadedFile = $request->file('datos_conductor_carnet_delantero');
    $storedPath = $uploadedFile->store('public/uploaded_files');

    // Store the stored file path in the session
    $request->session()->put('storedFilePath', $storedPath); */
    $archivoCarnetDelantero = $request->file('datos_conductor_carnet_delantero');
```

$rutaArchivo = $archivoCarnetDelantero->store('public/docs_conductor');

// Almacenar en la sesión solo el nombre del archivo
$request->session()->put('archivo_nombre', basename($rutaArchivo));

```
      //Mueve el Archivo
      //$rutaArchivo1 = $request->file('datos_conductor_carnet_delantero')->store('public/docs_conductor');
     /*  $carnet_delantero = $request->file('datos_conductor_carnet_delantero'); */

      //$archivos = $request->file('archivos');

      // Guardar el nombre del archivo en la sesión
      /* session()->put('archivos', $carnet_delantero->getClientOriginalName()); */
```

/*
$carnet_delantero->store('tmp');

```
    session()->put('carnet_delantero', $carnet_delantero->getFilename());
```

/*        if ($request->file("datos_conductor_carnet_delantero")) {
$file = $request->file("datos_conductor_carnet_delantero");

```
        $nombre = "pdf_" . time() . "." . $file->getClientOriginalName();

        // Almacenar el archivo en la carpeta 'docs_conductor' del sistema de almacenamiento
       $ruta =  Storage::put("public/docs_conductor/" . $nombre, file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
    } */
      //dd($nombre); */

    $request->session()->put('paso2', $data2); //Sesion de datos del form



        return redirect()->route('siniestros.paso3_vista');
    }
```

y la funcion para guardar en la base de datos por ahora asi:

```
 public function guardarSiniestroPublico(Request $request){ $fecha_actual = new \DateTime();

    //Guarda en tabla declaracion_siniestro
    $siniestro = new Siniestro();
    $siniestro->fecha_declaracion = $fecha_actual->format('Y-m-d');
    $siniestro->user_id = 0;
    $siniestro->tipo = 1;
    $siniestro->save();

    $idSiniestro = $siniestro->id;

    //Guarda en tabla vehiculo_siniestrados
    $data0 = $request->session()->get('paso0');
    $vehiculo_siniestrado = new VehiculoSiniestrado();
    $vehiculo_siniestrado->patente = $data0['vehiculo_siniestrado_patente'];
    $vehiculo_siniestrado->vin_chasis = $data0['vehiculo_siniestrado_chasis'];
    $vehiculo_siniestrado->num_motor = $data0['vehiculo_siniestrado_num_motor'];
    $vehiculo_siniestrado->marca = $data0['vehiculo_siniestrado_marca'];
    $vehiculo_siniestrado->modelo = $data0['vehiculo_siniestrado_modelo'];
    $vehiculo_siniestrado->anio = $data0['vehiculo_siniestrado_anio'];
    $vehiculo_siniestrado->declaracion_siniestro_id = $idSiniestro;
    $vehiculo_siniestrado->save();
    // Limpia la sesión
    $request->session()->forget('paso0');


    //Guarda en tabla datos_denunciantes
    $data1 = $request->session()->get('paso1');
    $datos_denunciantes = new DatosDenunciante();
    $datos_denunciantes->nombre_razon_social = $data1['datos_denunciante_nombre'];
    $datos_denunciantes->rut_cliente = $data1['datos_denunciante_rut_cliente'];
    $datos_denunciantes->rut_denunciante = $data1['datos_denunciante_rut_denunciante'];
    $datos_denunciantes->nombre_denunciante = $data1['datos_denunciante_nombre_denunciante'];
    $datos_denunciantes->ape_pat_denunciante = $data1['datos_denunciante_ape_pat'];
    $datos_denunciantes->ape_mat_denunciante = $data1['datos_denunciante_ape_mat'];
    $datos_denunciantes->tel_denunciante = $data1['datos_denunciante_telefono'];
    $datos_denunciantes->email_denunciante = $data1['datos_denunciante_email'];
    $datos_denunciantes->declaracion_siniestro_id = $idSiniestro;
    $datos_denunciantes->save();
    // Limpia la sesión
    $request->session()->forget('paso1');

    //Guarda en tabla datos_conductors
```

// Recuperar el nombre del archivo desde la sesión
$nombreArchivo = $request->session()->get('archivo_nombre');

// Construir la ruta completa
$rutaArchivoCompleta = storage_path('public/docs_conductor/' . $nombreArchivo);

```
    $docs_conductor = new DocssConductor();
    $docs_conductor->ruta_carnet_delantero = $rutaArchivoCompleta;
    $docs_conductor->declaracion_siniestro_id = $idSiniestro;
    $docs_conductor->save();

    }
```

Logro mover el archivo fisicamente a la carpeta pero me arroja el error antes señalado.

Agradeszco cualquier orientacion.

Slaudos

Answer (score 0):

$rutaArchivo1 esta regresando el objeto File en Si, debes obtener la URL del archivo puede ser con el metodo ->url() o metodo ->get() o especificamente convertir a string $rutaArchivo1

Comment: Hola, me podrías dar un ejemplo de como podría ser?

Comment: $request->session()->put('archivo', $rutaArchivo1); esta linea es la que esta causando el conflicto, en este caso,  $rutaArchivo1 es un objeto tipo file, y para guardarlo en "archivo" esta intentando serializarlo (convertir el objeto a string), pero tu no necesitas el objeto solo utilisas la ruta del archivo (/store/miDocumento.etc)

Comment: $request->file('datos_conductor_carnet_delantero')->store('public/docs_conductor')->url() o buscar con que url del archivo que te lo genero genero que seria "public/docs_conductor"."nombre del archivo",

Comment: $rutaArchivo1 = $request->session()->get('rutaArchivo1');  tambien intentas obtener rutaArchivo1 no "archivo"

Comment: gracias, estuve modificando el codigo (dejo la correcion en el post) pero me sigue arrojando el error: Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed